# Help with a select count query

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1111

I want to show all cities that have have a `count > 5`. I have tried to limit my results anything over a count of 5 but it isn't working.

```
SELECT
user.city,
Count(user.city) AS cnt
FROM user
Inner Join zip ON zip.zip = user.zip
WHERE cnt > 5
GROUP BY user.city
WHERE cnt > 5 **<--------------- It fails here**
```

`cnt` has already been defined in the field list so why doesn't work?

Answer (score 3):

you must use `having cnt > 4` when you are grouping

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html

Comment: +1: Also, GROUP BY/HAVING is the earliest that a column alias can be used in MySQL (and SQL Server), but ORDER BY is the earliest for standard SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Try `HAVING`

```
SELECT  user.city,
        COUNT(user.city) AS cnt
FROM user
INNER JOIN zip ON zip.zip = user.zip
GROUP BY user.city
HAVING COUNT(user.city) > 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the HAVING statement:

For example:

```
select title, AVG(salary)
from employee_data
GROUP BY title 
HAVING AVG(salary) > 100000;
```